# Vue.js v-bind:value to empty object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a dropdown that is populated with an array of objects.

```
<select v-model="selectedLeague" v-on:change="chooseLeague()">
    <option v-for="league in model.leagues" v-bind:value="league">
        {{  league.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

At initialization, selectedLeague is {}

I want to add a default option that is selected when the object is empty. I tried adding

```
<option disabled v-bind:value=null>Choose League</option>
```

But that will not work because it is never null. What can I add to check if the object is empty using data binding? I am using version 2.4.4 btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `selectedLeague` is initially `{}`, you can use:

```html
<option disabled v-bind:value="{}">Choose League</option>
```

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedLeague: {},
    model: {
     leagues: [{name: 'leagueOne'},{name: 'leagueTwo'}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    chooseLeague() { console.log('chooseLeague()', this.selectedLeague); }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.4"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedLeague" v-on:change="chooseLeague()">
    <option disabled v-bind:value="{}">Choose League</option>
    <option v-for="league in model.leagues" v-bind:value="league">
      {{ league.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Note: you can also add `hidden` if you want to hide that option from the dropdown:

```html
<option disabled v-bind:value="{}" hidden>Choose League</option>
```

Comment: Well TIL, that was easy!